# Google sheet - sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I did this post before but i did get the much anticipated help. Let me take this opportunity to try and be as clear as possible.
1. I have this google sheet  ID 1UJVQGlCpsxtqN-IkRFFgHEnzNaq-HQDaiw-hte5j3LY

```
Email Address   Name   Mark1    Mark2    Mark3  Remark  Email Sent
abc@gmail.com   John    34      21       34     Fair    
def@gmail.com   Sam     23      9        78     fair
```

2. Tamplate Doc. ID 15SP7mxyKYF6ptuRfrudNsvtJuezMTOBUL_cRCFbBIcI

Dear keyName

Mark1
Mark2
Mark3
keyMark_1
keyMark_2
keyMark_3

Remark
keyRemark

3. Code.

   // Email_Sent written in column G for rows for which an email
       // has been sent successfully.
       var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

   ```
   function sendEmails2() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
     var numRows = 5;   // Number of rows to process
     var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6)
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UJVQGlCpsxtqN-IkRFFgHEnzNaq-HQDaiw-hte5j3LY'); 
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Email Spreadsheet Data');
     //var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
     var copyId = DocsList.getFileById('15SP7mxyKYF6ptuRfrudNsvtJuezMTOBUL_cRCFbBIcI')
       .makeCopy(name)
       .getId();

     // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
     var data = dataRange.getValues();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
     //for (var j = 0; j < startRow; ++j) {
       var row = data[i];
       var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
       var name = row[1]; // Second column
       var Mark1 = row[2]; // Third column
       var Mark2 = row[3]; // Fourth column
       var Mark3 = row[4]; // 
       var remark = row[5]; // 
       var emailSent = row[6]; // 
       var static_copy = ('goins@mu.ac.ke');

       // Open the temporary document
     var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
     // Get the document’s body section
     var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

   // Replace place holder keys,in google doc template. Create a blank document with the number "1,2,3....", and it will replace this text with value
     copyBody.replaceText('keyName', name)
     copyBody.replaceText('keyMark_1', Mark1)
     copyBody.replaceText('keyMark_2', Mark2)
     copyBody.replaceText('keyMark_3', Mark3)
     copyBody.replaceText('keyRemark', remark)

   // Save and close the temporary document
     copyDoc.saveAndClose();

   // Convert temporary document to PDF
     var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

   // Attach PDF and send the email
     var subject = "Profile";
     var body = "<HTML><BODY>"
                + "Dear "+ name +",<br>"
                + "<br>"
                + " Regards <br>"
                + "<br>"
                + "</HTML></BODY>";

     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, 
                      {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf, cc: static_copy,});
    //if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
         //var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
        // MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf, cc: static_copy,});
       //sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Delete temp file
     DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);  
         } // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
       }
   ```

When i execute the above script, An email attachment with the John's marks is sent to both adc@gmail.com and efg@gmail.com.
I need your help in solving this issue to enable me to send each student an email attachment with there own results.

Kindly Help

Sammy.

Comment: You are trashing the file (copy id) and reopening it - how is that possible?

Comment: @Ark i was trashing at DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true to be able to fill the temporary doc. After commenting the line, it sends a duplicate attachment to all mails...

Comment: Sorry but question is too localized. Its an algorithm issue and not really an apps script issue.

Comment: @Zig Mandel I agree am new in this issue and i could use your help

Comment: This question reminds me of  [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260291/google-scripts-for-spreadsheets-if-statements/43261033#43261033)

Answer (score 3):

The `copyId` variable should be declared inside the for loop; the variable `name` is undefined when copyId is declared.

Also, you are using some deprecated API (DocsList for example).

Comment: Kindly here is an example of email attachment i get

Comment: Dear John
Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
34          21      34
Remark         Fair

Comment: When the mail salutation is Dear Sam.

Comment: Are you sure you have declared `copyId` after the `name` variable?

Comment: Kindly let me know how i could do this... am still new here, copyId according to your comment how do i do this

Comment: Thanks i did figure it out... thanks.. I needed to declare copyId in the loop....