# Google scripts for Spreadsheets (If statements)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hoping someone can help me with this issue. I am new to coding. I have a google spreadsheet with a script that pushes out an email. I am attempting to have the script ignore the rows where the script has already sent out an email on.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Email Menu')
    .addItem('Send Email', 'myFunction')
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();
};

function myFunction() {
  var msg = 'Email sent!';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
  var startRow = 2;

  for (i=1; i<values.length;i++) {

    //sent = values[i][4]; //added this in to try and skip a row if "X" was in Sent Column

    //if (sent ==" ", ) //added this in to try and skip a row if "X" was in Send Column

    var email = values[i][0];
    var name = values[i][i];
    var subject = values[i][2];
    var body = values[i][3];
    var sent = values[i][5];

    if (sent != EMAIL_SENT){
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i,5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
    }
 }}
```

[Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lcq1_Ge9FECnx61Z81frhRd1LsxL5O6LOCKkQ0mJmMc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `sheet.getRange(startRow + i,5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);` should be `sheet.getRange(startRow + i - 1, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);` according to the rest of the code.

Comment: That means `sent` column is F (column 6) not E (column 5)

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: @Theref1997, if one of the solutions has helped you, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Small fix. Replace

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i,5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

to

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i - 1, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

According to the rest of the script, this should be the most simple fix. This assumes `sent` column is `F` (column 6) not `E` (column 5). Sample sheet including updated script is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UzXh_iozVuMK_WQK6V2Rzp_E_h5do9TAyZSFsEO0Y6Q/).

And! You should change `var name = values[i][i];` to `var name = values[i][1];` as @jrook pointed. I missed it...

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following changes in your for loop:

```
for (i=1; i<values.length;i++) {

  var email = values[i][0];  
  var name = values[i][1]; //not [i][i] !  
  var subject = values[i][2];
  var body = values[i][3];  
  var sent = values[i][4];

  if (sent !== EMAIL_SENT){
    sheet.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  }

}
```

Basically get rid of the startRow variable (if you are not using elsewhere) and just use (i+1,5) to place "EMAIL_SENT" in the right column. I have removed parts of your code for the sake of clarity.